# How do i take median of 5 grayscale frames?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am taking input from a video and I want to take the median value of the first 5 frames so that I can use it as background image for motion detection using deferential.

Also, I want to use a time condition that, say if motion is not detected then calculate the background again, else wait t seconds. I am new to opencv and I don't know how to do it.. Please help

Also, I want to take my video in 1 fps but this does not work. Here is the code I have:

```
import cv2

BLUR_SIZE = 3
NOISE_CUTOFF = 12

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('gh10fps.mp4')
cam.set(3, 640)
cam.set(4, 480)

cam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 1)
fps=cam.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)  
print "Current FPS: ",fps
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your "code", what have you actually tried?

Comment: Are you aware, that OpenCV has built-in background subtractor algorithms you can use? Also there is the excellent Background Subtraction Library:

https://github.com/andrewssobral/bgslibrary

Comment: @Georg Sir, how do i use this library in python.. this library is for cpp i guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the median of the first 5 frames, then following should do what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frames = []

for _ in range(5):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frames.append(gray)

median = np.median(frames, axis=0).astype(dtype=np.uint8)    
cv2.imshow('frame', median)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note, this is just taking the source from a webcam as an example.